# Code to pick a folder path to save multiple spreadsheets in a workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have a workbook with multiple spreadsheets and am looking to save them as individual csv files (retaining the file name from their respective spreadsheets) in a folder of my choosing.

The following code seems to let me choose a path, but errors out with the following message:
Error code 9 
Subscript out of range on this line
    For Each ws In Sheets(Array("01 - Currencies", "...., "14 - User Defined
    Fields"))
What am I missing?

```
Sub SaveOnlyCSVsThatAreNeeded()
Dim ws As Worksheet, newWb As Workbook
Dim pathh As Variant

Dim FolderName As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = -1 Then
       FolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

pathh = FolderName

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("01 - Currencies", "...., "14 - User Defined  
Fields"))

ws.Copy
Set newWb = ActiveWorkbook
With newWb
  .SaveAs pathh.path & "\" & ws.Name, xlCSV
  .Close (False)
End With
Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a typo? Change the line to `For Each ws In Sheets(Array("01 - Currencies", "....", "14 - User Defined Fields"))`  and if that still doesn't work, then make sure you have worksheets named as such in your workbook. I just tested that line and it worked for me.

Comment: I think the answer below is on the right track. You seem to be losing the parent workbook that holds the array of worksheets. `dim wb as workbook: set wb = activeworkbook` then `For Each ws In wb.Sheets(Array(...` should take care of the loss of focus when you are opening the worksbooks. Of course, this all assumes that your array of worksheet names contains no typos.

Comment: @Jeeped - I just used these three lines, `For Each ws In Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "sheet3")) //
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "A" //
Next ws` and it worked in a sample workbook I created. I'm assuming then you're right, he just needs to assign parentage to the Sheets?

Comment: @BruceWayne - The OP probably has parentage on the first pass but loses it after opening a workbook. Even after closing the workbook, there is still a reliance on focus being passed back correctly. There is problematic; defining the parent would at least remove that from the possibilities regarding the problem's origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond the question of each worksheet's parent workbook, there was a problem with `pathh.Path`. `FolderName` is already the full path of the folder selected; you do not need to find its `.Path`. This would produce:

> <sup>Runtime error 424: Object required.</sup>

```
Sub SaveOnlyCSVsThatAreNeeded()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim pathh As Variant

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then  'a folder was picked
           pathh = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    If pathh = False Then Exit Sub   'no folder picked; pathh is false

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4"))
        ws.Copy
        With ActiveWorkbook
            'Application.DisplayAlerts = False   'to avoid overwrite warnings
            '  pathh is a string (variant) of the path of the folder; does not need pathh.Path
            .SaveAs pathh & "\" & ws.Name, xlCSV
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Don't forget to double-check the worksheets names in the array for typos.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
```

Or

```
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("01 - Currencies", "14 - User Defined  Fields"))
```

Comment: This works, assuming he wants to loop through all worksheets.  He'd need to do something like `If ws.Name like Array(#) Then` to make sure it runs on only the sheets he wants.